# How to use index hint in this query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
match (s:Product {type:'Phone'})-[r]->(o:Attributes)
USING INDEX o:Attributes(resolution)
WHERE any(key in keys(o) WHERE key='resolution' AND o[key] contains '2000')
return s, o limit 2
```

I have two questions with this query:

1) It reports an error in this syntax for 'USING INDEX o:Attributes(resolution)', which isn't allowed.

2) The reason I am using this 'where' clause format is that my key&value will be variables passed through function. The WHERE clause actually looks like this:

```
WHERE any(key in keys(o) WHERE key=$kgKey AND o[key] = $kgValue)
```

Hopefully, I can the first problem resolved first, and then try to solve the 2nd problem.

EDIT:
What I want to achieve in this query is: find out all phones with a specific 'resolution' value, i.e. 'resolution=2000'. Since the clause will filter on other similar properties as 'resolution' too, i can't hard code 'resolution' in the query.

And to allow for partial match, I use o[key] CONTAINS '2000', instead of =.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index is associated with a *specify property* of a node label, and currently the Cypher planners are only smart enough to support a subset of the ways in which an indexed property could be specified in a `MATCH/WHERE` pair. You may have received an error message that started something like this:

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Cannot use index hint in this
>   context. Index hints are only supported for the following predicates
>   in WHERE (either directly or as part of a top-level AND or OR):
>   equality comparison, inequality (range) comparison, STARTS WITH, IN
>   condition or checking property existence. The comparison cannot be
>   performed between two property values. Note that the label and
>   property comparison must be specified on a non-optional node ...

You can try creating indexes on multiple properties of `Attributes`, and the Cypher planner *might* generate a plan that uses all of them (use the [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) option to check the generated plan).

*But, if you also have an index on `:Product(type)`, you may want to drop it (since that index could match a lot of nodes and worsen your performance due to the creation of a large cartesian product).*

For example, if you had 3 `Attributes` properties (resolution, foo, and bar) and you had indexes on all of them, the Cypher planner *might* generate a plan that uses all 3 indexes on a query that looks like this:

```
MATCH (s:Product {type:'Phone'})-->(o:Attributes)
WHERE o.resolution = '2000' OR o.foo = 123 OR o.bar = 'abc'
RETURN s, o
LIMIT 2;
```

Unfortunately, you cannot add `USE INDEX` hints to tell the planner to use all your indexes, since another current limitation is that you can only provide a single index hint per variable (such as `o`).

Comment: Hi， @cybersam, I came back to this question again. Since the query above in my question represents a very general pattern, i.e. 'find some type of nodes with meet certain conditions' . There is nothing special about it, but it still quite slow. For example, if the instances of 'Phone' is a few millions, it becomes slow. How can this be practically used? What about other users' needs? Do they have similar issues? I am asking this because my query seems to me not unique, and my graph model is 'normal' too.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is actually not common, since: (a) it is *structured to look like* it requires iteration through all the properties of a node instead of looking at specific properties, and (b) it is filtering by CONTAINS instead of equality. Either one of those characteristics alone would prevent the use of indexes.

Comment: Now, you could have simplified that `WHERE` clause to the logically equivalent `WHERE o.resolution contains '2000'`, but the use of "CONTAINS" would still prevent the use of an index.

Comment: The problem is that my 'resolution' would be variable passed from a function, because I have to use the query in an application. In real code, resolution, node type etc. would be variables, not the actual string or integer. Isn't this also common? Let's say on a web form, users types whatever to fill the blanks, and those values become variables too, which will be used in SQL query or graph query. Isn't that the case? Rarely real users would just make and execute the query in the Neo4j Browser. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi, @cybersam, any suggestions on how to change the model to deal with this situation? This is a very typical query pattern in my application.

Comment: The set of property names needed for most queries are known ahead of time and hardcoded in the queries. Normally, it is the property *values* that are input parameters. In your sample query, it is very uncommon that there will be a number of properties that need to be tested against the same value ("2000").

Comment: "need to be tested against the same value ("2000")": The reason for that  is the property name is unknown. Or I only want to find entities that have some type of "property value", in which case the property name doesn't matter, or the property name is a candidate list, which needs to be tested. I extract property name, value or node labels from users' question of natural languages. It's nearly impossible to hardcode all property names in the query. Any other possible way to walk around the bottleneck of performance?

Comment: You need to design your data model to work well with the DB. For example, if every `Attribute` has at most one attribute value, then it can always have a "value" property for that value. If you also want it to contain the attribute type, then it can have a "type" property for that.

Comment: Can you give one example? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you pass in `prop` and `val` parameters: `MATCH (s:Product {type:'Phone'})-->(o:Attribute)
WHERE o.type = $prop AND o.value = $val
RETURN s, o LIMIT 2;`

Comment: If one of my existing Attribute node has properties: length, width & height, so I need to create new 3 labels: Length:Attribute, Width:Attribute and Height:Attribute. Basically split each property of the Attribute node into individual nodes. And for all the attribute nodes, I have at least 2 properties: attrName & attrValue. Right?

Comment: Yes. Also, you could index whatever property gets you to your answer fastest (e.g., `:Attribute(value)` if you do not expect the same `value` to occur that often).

Comment: In that case, my number of Attribute nodes will explode, since one Attribute node currently have 30 properties on average. And also each Attribute node will typically have only 2 properties: type & value. Is that normal for a graph design?

Comment: Even without considering the number of ndoes, I still can't use 'USING INDEX o:Attributes(resolution)' to speed up due to the 'where' clause. Right?

Comment: Your use case is unusual because you seem to want to query on any arbitrary property, and it seems the set of properties can change dynamically. Most data models have a fixed set of properties (or a set that grows gradually and gracefully over time).

Comment: The set of properties won't change once the graph is built. What can't be fixed is which property will be queried on at query time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168598/discussion-between-cybersam-and-user697911).